# What sign -> means in spock framework?

Tags: spock

Could anyone explain me what means sign -> in spock framework?

For exaple we have code like below:

```
given:
    UserService service = Stub()
    service.save({ User user -> 'Michael' == user.name }) >> {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("We don't want you here, Micheal!")
    }
```

I know what this code do, but I dont know how role have sign -> in this code.

Comment: Looks like a lambda to me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Spock Framework assumes a basic level of understanding of the Groovy language and sometimes the more intricate parts of Groovy show up (like in your example).

The `->` denotes a **closure** as described in the [Groovy documentation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Closures).

For instance, a closure in Groovy could look like this:

```
def greeting = "Hello"
def sayHiTo = { name -> greeting + " " + name }
println sayHiTo("user3664097")
```